# How To Capture information about Virtual Machine resources that will be destroyed?

Tags: terraform

### Background

I was kind of dropped into an IaC project that uses Packer => Terraform  => Ansible to create RHEL Virtual Machines on an on-prem VMware Vsphere cluster.

Our vmware module registers output variables that we use once the VMs are created, those variables feed a  local_file resource template to build an Ansible inventory with the vm names and some other variables.

Ansible is then run using local_exec with the above created inventory to do configuration actions and run scripts both on the newly deployed VM's and against some external management applications, for example to join the VM to a domain (FreeIPA, sadly no TF good provider is available).

### Issue Description

The issue that I have been wrestling with is when we run a terraform destroy (or apply with some VM count changes that destroy a VM resource), we would like to be able to repeat the process in reverse.

**Capture the names of the VMs to be destroyed(Output vars from resource creation) so they can be removed from the IPA domain** and have some general cleanup.

We've tried different approaches with Destroy Time Provisioners and it just seems like it would require a fundamental change in the approach outlined above to make that work.

### Question

**I'm wondering if there is a way to get an output variable on destroy that could be used to populate a list the VMs that would be removed.**

So far my search has turned up nothing. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is good to plan first, even when destroying:

```
terraform plan -destroy -out tfplan
```

Then, you you can proceed with the destroy:

```
terraform apply tfplan
```

But at this moment (or before actual destroy), you have a plan what was destroyed, and you can do any analysis or automation on it. Example:

```
terraform show -json tfplan | jq > tfplan.json
```

Source:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/plan

Comment: Thank you for such an quick and elegant solution. I knew there was an angle that I had missed. Getting json from the plan command is brilliant.

Comment: Glad to be of help, really!

Comment: Just to follow up on this old thread. The best approach I found was 
parsing the json output with PowerShell. The output of a plan is IMO very complicated and turning it into PowerShell Objects  was very helpful. I could then write functions and other actions on the output.